# Evaluate $\lim _ { x \rightarrow 0} \frac { \tan ( x ^ { a } ) - ( \sin x ) ^ { a } } { x ^ { a + 2} }$

Tags: limits

For $a \geq 1$, evaluate $\lim _ { x \rightarrow 0} \frac { \tan ( x ^ { a } ) - ( \sin x ) ^ { a } } { x ^ { a + 2} }$

I would like to solve this without Taylor's expansion. I've tried adding and subtracting $x^a$ but I don't know if this is a correct approach. I've also tried L'Hospital and reached the result $(a^2 - a) /(6a +12). $

Comment: just out of curiosity, why the aversion to Taylor's and not Lhopitals? They are functionally the same

Comment: I haven't studied Taylor's at all in (high) school and am not very familiar with it.

Comment: @AndreiOnoie All the more reason you may find it useful.

Comment: It is much better to avoid L'Hospital's Rule which champions the idea that *if plugging does not work then differentiate and plug*. Taylor series is a very natural way to handle limits provided you have studied it's proof (to know why it's the *natural* way).

Comment: And as you can see the answer you got via L'Hospital's Rule is incorrect (may be some calculation mistake). You can show your work if you need help in finding the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a positive integer then there is an easy approach via factorization. Let us first deal with $a=1$. We have $$\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^{3}} =\frac{\sin x} {x} \frac{1}{\cos x} \frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}\to \frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$ Also note that using L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series we can easily show that $$\frac{\tan x- x} {x^{3}}\to \frac{1}{3}\tag{2}$$ and subtracting these above two limits we see that $$\frac{x-\sin x} {x^{3}}\to\frac{1}{6}\tag{3}$$ For general integer $a>1$ we have $$\frac{\tan x^{a} - x^{a}} {x^{a+2}} = \frac{\tan x^{a} - x^{a}} {x^{3a}} \cdot x^{2(a-1)}\to\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0=0\tag{4}$$ and $$\frac{x^{a} -\sin^{a} x} {x^{a+2}}=\frac{x-\sin x} {x^{3}}\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}\frac{x^{a-1-i}}{x^{a-1-i}}\frac{\sin^{i}x}{x^{i}}\to\frac{1}{6}\cdot a=\frac{a} {6}\tag{5}$$ Adding equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ we get the desired answer as $a/6$. If $a$ is not an integer then you need to resort to powerful technique of Taylor series as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

if $a=1$,
$$\tan (x)=x+\frac {x^3}{3}(1+\epsilon_1 (x)) $$

$$\sin (x)=x-\frac {x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$

the limit is $\frac {1}{2} $.

if $a>1$

$$(\sin (x))^a=e^{a(\ln (x)+\ln (1-\frac {x^2}{6}(1+\epsilon_2(x)))} $$
$$=x^a(1-\frac {ax^2}{6}(1+\epsilon_2 (x)) )$$

the limit is $$\frac {a}{6} $$